# How to show a specific UIViewController when GKGameCenterViewController is dismissed?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-center, gamekit

I am presenting a `GKGameCenterViewController` in an SKScene that inherits from the following protocol.

```
protocol GameCenter {}
extension GameCenter where Self: SKScene {

    func goToLeaderboard() {
        let vc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        vc.gameCenterDelegate = GameViewController()
        vc.viewState = .leaderboards
        vc.leaderboardIdentifier = "leaderboard"
        view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

While the `GKGameCenterViewController` shows up perfect, when I try to dismiss by clicking the X in the top right corner, nothing happens. I assume this is because the reference to my original `GameViewController` has been deallocated. How can I get this dismissal to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to present the `GKGameCenterViewController` on a SKScene, I needed to find the currently displayed `UIViewController` reference and set this as the delegate. Here is the code I used and it works:

```
protocol GameCenter {}
extension GameCenter where Self: SKScene {
    
    func goToLeaderboard() {
        var currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        let vc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        vc.gameCenterDelegate = currentViewController as! GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
        vc.viewState = .leaderboards
        vc.leaderboardIdentifier = "leaderboard"
        currentViewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkgamecentercontrollerdelegate/1520771-gamecenterviewcontrollerdidfinis):

> Your delegate should dismiss the Game Center view controller. If your game paused any gameplay or other activities, it can restart those services in this method.

This means you need to implement the `gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish` method in your delegate and dismiss the `gameCenterViewController` yourself.

You should have something like this in your `GameViewController()`

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I already have this in my ```GameViewController``` the problem arises when I try to present the ```GKGameCenterViewController``` from an ```SKScene```. That's why I attempted to use a protocol that the ```SKScene``` could inherit from. Is there a way that I could set the delegate to ```GameViewController``` from the protocol?